# Laravel Validator checks if field value is equal to "My prefer value"

Tags: php, laravel, validation, eloquent

Currently I can check if the `emp_id` from array exists in my table `users`

I'm matching `emp_id` to `company_id` if it exists or not.

using this working code

```
 foreach ($arr3 as $row3) {
                $insert_data3[] = array(
                    'projCode'  =>  $projCode,
                    'emp_id'  =>  $row3['pm_member_code'],
                    'type'  =>  'PM',
                    'deleted'  =>  0,
                    'by_id'  => auth()->user()->id,
                    'updated_by'    =>  auth()->user()->name,
                    'created_at'    =>  now(),
                    'updated_at'    => now(),
                );
            }
            $validatorSave3 = Validator::make(
                $insert_data3,
                [
                    '*.emp_id' => "required|exists:users,company_id",
                ],
                [
                    '*.emp_id.exists' => 'The selected :attribute is invalid. Project Manager does not exists!',
                ]
            );
```

Now what I want to do is to check using the validator above. If `account_type` field has the value of `WEB` for that `company_id`

Like this : `account_type = "WEB"` and if `account_type` doesn't equal to `WEB` validator will tell that the `account_type` is not equal to `WEB`

Here's my `users` table

[image]